# Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Tags: codeigniter, fatal-error

my database was in mssql which I migrated into mysql using workbench migration wizard.But after i target my application to my new migrated database i get this error.

My database.php file looks fine with correct database name,hostname,pw and username. Still getting the same issue.

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Comment: Share your `database.php` detail

Comment: has nothing to do with databases. verify that your entire system folder copied over correctly. if not, delete the system folder and download a fresh copy.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be at all related to databases. You seem to be trying to extend `CI_Controller` from a class that has no access to CI's base controller. Have you by any chance changed from a Windows to a Linux server, changed from CI 2.x to 3.x or any other major change in your environment in addition to the database server?

Comment: JavierLarroulet it was working all correctly in our server(windows).. There was a need to do a fresh migration and after migrating the application stopped working.I didnt do any change in code..just migrated the database and when pointing the application to the new database gives me this error

Comment: i have not made any changes to the code..and it was working in our server correctly